# Fancy tree lazyLoad event handler with Children nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, fancytree

I have a hierarchical tree structure which looks something like this:

```
-Folder1 (expanded = true, lazy = false)
--Folder2 (expanded = true, lazy = false)
---Folder3 (expanded = false, lazy = true)
----item1 (expanded = false, lazy = true)
----item2 (expanded = false, lazy = true)
```

I was trying to define the event handler lazyLoad, but realized it wasn't getting called when I expanded folder3 (a lazy node). When looking into it I found in the [documentation](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/TutorialLoadData):

> If node.lazy is true and node.children is null or undefined, the lazyLoad event is triggered, when this node is expanded.

Which explained why the lazyLoad event wasn't being triggered(This node had children). Why is having no children a prerequisite for the handler to be called and is there any way around this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fancy tree lazyLoad event handler with Children nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64580712/fancy-tree-lazyload-event-handler-with-children-nodes)

Comment: Looks like it posted twice. I deleted the duplicate post.